# JQuery color picker frustration

Tags: jquery, color-picker

I need a color picker for jQuery, like a certain blue monster needs cookies. I have been trying to use [this one](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#about), but have had [problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998135/jquery-color-picker-z-axis-problem)...

The thing that has me frustrated is that on the jQuery [themeroller page](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/)(look under content) they are using one! Why don't they support it? It looks like the farbtastic color-picker, but there's no documentation on how to use it like they do in the themeroller(which is exactly what I want to do).

Has anyone had luck with color-picker plugins? Can you suggest me some, or show me where there is documentation on how to use them?

Comment: The color picker (its name is `ui-colorpicker`) that you've seen on the jQuery ThemeRoller page is no longer a part of jQuery UI. Read more there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/971152/jquery-ui-color-picker, http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137750/ColorPicker.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion by `Jami` on your other post? Messing with the `z-index` is a good place to start. It seems you've sort of abandoned that question after asking it.

Comment: @Dutchie432 Haha I haven't abandoned it, Jami only posted that answer 20 min ago!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plugin used by the jQuery UI Theme Builder is Farbtastic. Check it out at [the developer's site](http://acko.net/dev/farbtastic).

Comment: Cool. Any ideas then how they are making the colorpicker div appear and disappear when you click on the input textbox? That's what I want to do, and that's what the colorpicker I was using previously did so well.

Comment: Just bind a [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) for the colorpicker container to your input's [.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) event and a [.hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) to the colorpicker's [.blur()](http://api.jquery.com/blur/). Something along those lines anyway. Might be slightly more complex but that's the short of it.

Comment: On second thought, place them in the same containing object and bind those show and hides to the parent container's focus/blur. That way if neither the picker or input has focus, the picker hides.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. Maybe I'll figure out a way to make it work only using the object's class eventually

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/lthibodeaux/je9kn/) is a fiddle that demonstrates how the jQUI theme roller accomplishes the task (more or less). I do use Josh Bush's [input mask plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) to sanitize custom user input.

Comment: Yes, your previous help led me to very similar code, but with one problem. I modified your fiddle to represent [my code](http://jsfiddle.net/je9kn/3/). 
You see that the problem is in this line:  $(".aColorPicker").farbtastic("#anInput"); 
I don't know how to make #andInput generic to fit the rest of the generic function.

Comment: [See this revision](http://jsfiddle.net/je9kn/4/). You could just as easily change $(this).siblings("input") to $(this).prev() but I wanted to genericize it in the event some other markup ended up between the two elements.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good list of different color pickers here:

http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137750/ColorPicker

Cheers